# Adding to cart problem (What am I missing)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

What am missing in code?
Any suggestions?

Error display like this:-

```
Error Type:
Microsoft JET Database Engine (0x80040E14)
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'orderID =1AND productID ='.
/mcartfree/addToCart.asp, line 49
```

Code is so far

```
'Main program 
 Sub CreateNewOrder()
    Application.lock
    if Application("orderID") = "" then
        Application("orderID") = 1
    end if


   intOrderID = Application("orderID")
   Session("orderID") = intOrderID
   Conn.Execute("INSERT INTO orders " _
    & " (orderID, status) values " _
    & " ("&intOrderID&", 'OPEN')")

    Application("orderID") = Application("orderID") + 1
   Application.Unlock
End Sub

Sub AddToOrder(nOrderID, nProductID, nQuant)
    sqlText = "INSERT INTO itemsOrdered " _
        & " (orderID, productID, quantity) values " _ 
        & " ("&nOrderID&", "&nProductID&", "&nQuant&")"
    Conn.Execute(sqlText)

End Sub


'Main program 
intProdID = Request.form("intProdID")
intQuant = Request.form("intQuant")

set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open ConString

intOrderID = cstr(Session("orderID"))
if intOrderID = "" then
   CreateNewOrder
end if

sqlText = "SELECT * FROM itemsOrdered WHERE orderID =" & intOrderID & "AND productID =" & intProdID
set rsOrder = Conn.Execute(sqlText)

if rsOrder.EOF then
    txtInfo = "This item has been added to your order."  
    AddToOrder intOrderID, intProdID, intQuant
else
    txtInfo = "This item is already in your cart."
end if
```

New Error

```
Error Type:
Microsoft JET Database Engine (0x80004005)
Operation must use an updateable query.
/mcartfree/addToCart.asp, line 19
```

Now again the new error

```
Error Type:
Microsoft JET Database Engine (0x80004005)
Operation must use an updateable query.
/mcartfree/addToCart.asp, line 31
```

Comment: you might want to show us some code don't you thing?

Comment: @Carsten König :) I m unable to edit the Question

Comment: sqlText = "SELECT * FROM itemsOrdered WHERE orderID =" & intOrderID & "AND productID =" & intProdID
 set rsOrder = Conn.Execute(sqlText)

Comment: @Carsten König:) Question edited but not the whole code

Comment: Number 1... Try using a stored procedure. If you can't change your code to a Parameterized SQL statement http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are missing whitespace `orderID = 1 AND productID =` instead of `orderID =1AND productID =`.

I your case system can't find `AND` operator becuase it's represented in query like value `1AND` for `orderId` field.

Update your query with the following:

```
sqlText = "SELECT * FROM itemsOrdered WHERE orderID = " & intOrderID & " AND productID = " & intProdID
set rsOrder = Conn.Execute(sqlText)
                                                     ^                  ^               ^
                                                 whitespace         whitespace!!!   whitespace
```

Comment: Error Type:
Microsoft JET Database Engine (0x80040E14)
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'orderID = 1 AND productID ='.
/mcartfree/addToCart.asp, line 49

Comment: Try to get formatted `sqlText` variable and if it's possible post here. Somethign like `Response.Write(sqlText`. And comment `set rsOrder = Conn.Execute(sqlText)`

Comment: Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

Comment: You can put only up to 600 chars in the comment :)

Comment: Sub CreateNewOrder()
        Application.lock
        if Application("orderID") = "" then
   Application("orderID") = 1
        end if
       
        
       intOrderID = Application("orderID")
       Session("orderID") = intOrderID
       Conn.Execute("INSERT INTO orders " _
  & " (orderID, status) values " _
  & " ("&intOrderID&", 'OPEN')")
  
  Application("orderID") = Application("orderID") + 1
       Application.Unlock
    End Sub

Comment: What is it? It looks like something different

Comment: @ Samich:) actualy i want show my whole code but unable to do that

Comment: now the next Error Type:
Microsoft JET Database Engine (0x80004005)
Operation must use an updateable query.
/mcartfree/addToCart.asp, line 19

Comment: :) see now i m able to edit the Question, same error right now when i replace ur codes ...

Comment: For the last posted error checkout this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175168. It could be couple reasons.

Comment: Error Type:
Microsoft JET Database Engine (0x80004005)
Operation must use an updateable query.
/mcartfree/addToCart.asp, line 19 and line 19 code is  Conn.Execute("INSERT INTO orders " _
  & " (orderID, status) values " _
  & " ("&intOrderID&", 'OPEN')")

Comment: :) Bro i m not able to do that can u plz sugest me

Comment: I don't know what to suggest :) .. Try to set to your connection `Conn.Mode = 3` before opening connection. Maybe it helps.

Comment: i m trying this but does not work !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!aset Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Conn.Mode = 3      '3 = adModeReadWrite
    Conn.Open ConString

Comment: And your `Internet Guest account (IUSR_MACHINE)` have write rights?

Comment: Check that IUser has read and write permissions at the very least on the directory in which you keep your Access file. Do you have the access file there? If so, check that you can run the queries in Access.

Comment: BTW If this is intended to be a real shopping site, Access is not a suitable choice, and I am an Access fan.

Comment: _When using Microsoft Access databases with ADO, it is also necessary to give the Internet Guest account Write permissions on the directory containing the .mdb file. This is because Jet creates an .ldb file to handle database locking. You may also need to give read/write permission on the "Temp" folder because Jet may create temporary files in this directory._

Comment: @Samich:)I think i have need to Permissions on the database itself must be set to Read, Write, Execute and Delete.

Comment: @Samich:)Thanks my dear Friend

Answer (score 0):

Write out your SQL string and see if its correct:

```
sqlText = "SELECT * FROM itemsOrdered WHERE orderID = " & intOrderID & " AND productID = " & intProdID
' Debug sql...
Response.Write(sqlText)
Response.End()
' Just debuging the SQL statement....

set rsOrder = Conn.Execute(sqlText)
```

Comment: What line is 31? is it the AddToOrder method that runs? what happens if you write the SQL statement like the code above? And does you have the rights to update/insert your Access database?